# How to calculate the p-value for a binomial test using pbinom?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

25 patients receive treatment, and they each get a difference score (After-Before). 18 of them get positive scores. I would like to test the null hypothesis that p=0.5.

I know that `1-pbinom(17,25,0.5)` gives me the probability of 18 or more patients getting a positive score. My question is, to calculate the p-value, why do we have to do

```
2*(1-pbinom(17,25,0.5))
```

That is, why do we multiply by 2 here?

Answer (score 8):

If you do not multiply by 2, you will be evaluating the probability of having scores ranging from 18 to 25 (one-sided test).

Multiplying by 2, you are evaluating the probability of having scores ranging from 0 to 7 and 18 to 25 (two-sided test).
Your command results in an answer similar to this one:

```
binom.test(18, 25, 0.5, alternative="two.sided")
```